# How do you exclude xml files when tomcat startup with Jrebel

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, jrebel

I've been working on a project with Spring + Flex BlazeDS.

I want to use Jrebel remote debug with tomcat. But here's the problem. It seems Jrebel failed to recognize Flex BlazeDS xml tag. So when I enabled Jrebel in catalina.bat and try to start up tomcat. My app in tomcat webapps failed to start up on context initialization because Jrebel failed to recognize the xml tag.

> [2014-Oct-24 17:13:02,503][main:ERROR][ContextLoader]  Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 27 in XML document from
>   ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/RemotingContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xm
>   l.sax.SAXParseException: Element type "flex:" must be followed by either attribute specifications, "
>   " or "/>".
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBe
>   anDefinitionReader.java:396)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBean
>   DefinitionReader.java:334)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBean
>   DefinitionReader.java:302)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinition
>   s(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinition
>   s(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinition
>   s(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlW
>   ebApplicationContext.java:124)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlW
>   ebApplicationContext.java:93)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFact
>   ory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(Abs
>   tractApplicationContext.java:467)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.__refresh(AbstractApplicat
>   ionContext.java:397)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicatio
>   nContext.java)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.j
>   ava:282)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.jav
>   a:204)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderLis
>   tener.java:47)

My xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:flex="http://www.springframework.org/schema/flex"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/flex
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/flex/spring-flex-1.5.xsd
">

<flex:message-broker>
    <flex:exception-translator ref="allExceptionTranslator"/>
    <flex:remoting-service default-channels="my-amf" />
    <flex:message-service default-adapter-id="jms" default-channels="my-polling-amf" />
</flex:message-broker>

<flex:message-destination id="newSystemDate"/>


<flex:remoting-destination ref="mainPanelService"/>
<flex:remoting-destination ref="tradeService"/> </beans>
```

Is there a way to config Jrebel to recognize Flex BlazeDS xml tag? 
If not, I want to exclude those xmls on tomcat startup so Jrebel won't try to load it and fail to startup the whole app.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know which line is 27th line that causes problems? It's hard to determine it based on this xml section, since it doesn't contain 27 lines.

Comment: <flex:message-destination id="newSystemDate"/>   it's this xml tag that Jrebel failed to recognize and validate

Comment: I don't think there's a problem with the xml. My app started well without Jrebel. But with it, it couldn't be started in tomcat. I want to know if there's a way even I got a broken xml in my classpath. It will still run successfully

Comment: You might want to turn to support@zeroturnaround.com with the issue, not just exclude some files.